# Can't execute the Kotlin Project after adding an activity to the Manifest File

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, manifest

I have a very simple Project right now and all I did, is I added another Activity to the Manifest File exactly the way as I did before (and it worked), after I tried to execute the program I got this error message in the Logs:

> 2023-03-29 17:15:30.253  4215-4215  studio.deploy           pid-4215                             E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.kotlin/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory

After reversing the Changes and leaving the Code the way it was, the error did not disappear, I do understand that it tries to delete some cache Files which it can't find however I have no idea why it tries to do so and how to fix this. Thanks for the Help

Comment: Did you try to go to Build -> Rebuild Project in Android Studio? If that doesn't help, also try File -> Invalidate Caches... -> Invalidate Caches and Restart. This procedure often fixes strange issues.

Comment: tried `build -> clean project` ?